# How to insert text string into ttk Entry?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I want to add/delete a string to `ttk` `Entry`. How?
I'm new in `tkinter` `Entry` but I don't know how in `ttk` `Entry`.

This is code to insert any string in `tkinter` `Entry`:

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

my_entry = Entry(root,font=("arial",10,"bold")).pack()
my_entry.insert(0, "GG") # Working :)

root.mainloop()
```

so I don't know How in the `ttk` Entry Help:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
root = tk.Tk()

my_entry = ttk.Entry(root,font=("arial",10,"bold")).pack()

my_entry.insert(0, "GG")  #Not Working :(

root.tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yeah and Thinks

Comment: well that has to be said in the documentation but I wont be able to help more than that as I have never worked with ttk

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Comment: Your both examples will produce the exact same error.

Comment: Really cool guys I fixed it with you thanks very much :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line like this:

```
my_entry = ttk.Entry(root,font=("arial",10,"bold"))
my_entry.pack()
```

It is the wrong way to say `Entry(..).pack()` in python as in python `x = a().b()`, `x` will get the value returned by `b()` in this case `pack()` and `pack()` returns `None` so then `my_entry` becomes `None`, so your trying to call `insert()` in `None`, which will give you the error your facing

> AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute insert()

Final Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
root = tk.Tk()

my_entry = ttk.Entry(root,font=("arial",10,"bold"))
my_entry.pack()

my_entry.insert(0, "GG")  #Not Working :(

root.tk.mainloop()
```

Also keep a note, that your first and second examples in Q will give the exact same error.

Comment: The same :(    I mean How to insert\delete in that entry

Comment: @ShihabAl-den Updated the answer, with entire code, just try copy pasting the code.

Comment: This question is obviously duplicated with another question.You are an expert on tkinter.Why don't you flag it directly?

Comment: @KevinMayo Yes there are almost 100s of Q on this site similar to this, but the problem is that OP might not just understand it directly, I have voted to close the Q, but an answer here so that the OP can understand what to do in their case, like you see the above comment, OP is still confused(I think).

Comment: @CoolCloud Understand.

Comment: "It is not recommended…"? is an understatement. More to the point — it's simply the **wrong** way to be doing things.

Comment: Cool thanks it's solved :D